# Check if directory does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a script to check in var/log directory, and it takes all the directories in there and checks if there is an archive directory in those directories. If an archive directory not exist, I want to create it, but once it's created the script tries to create it again.

```bash
vdir=$(sudo sh -c "find /var/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name "archive"" )
for i in $vdir ;do
    echo $i
    if [[ ! -d $i/$arc ]];then
        sudo sh -c "mkdir $i/$arc"
        echo "$date:$HN:Creating:$i/$arc:directory" >> logrotation.log
    fi
done
```

When I execute above code it gives me this error. Seems the script is not checking the condition.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/speech-dispatcher/archive’: File exists
```

Comment: What does  `$arc` contain?

Comment: It ia a varibale for to create archive directory, it is mention as below.
arc=archive

Comment: You cannot nest double quotes in the first `sudo sh -c "find ..."`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue is that you have two `[` symbols.  You only need one:

```
          if [ ! -d $i/$arc ];then
```

An additional point: some shell versions don't handle the `;` being right next to the closing bracket.  Thus, I'd suggest formatting like this for best compatibility:

```
          if [ ! -d $i/$arc ] ; then
```

**Edit: since the above didn't help you, more thoughts:**

It's also entirely possible that your script, running as you, can't actually read the contents of the `$i` directory and thus the test will always fail (or succeed, actually).  But, when you create the directory as root via sudo, it already exists.

[It would also be more efficient to run the entire script under sudo rather than just certain pieces of it.]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have made this changes, Nothing happen. Still trying to create directory when is is there, But for some directory it work. Not sure the reason of it.

Comment: Huh? `[[` is the Bash souped-up replacement for traditional `[`.  It works just fine as long (as your shell is in fact Bash!) and certainly does not produce the error message described by the OP.